# Vert.x - GraphQL Subscriptions with DataInputStreams

Tags: java, graphql, vert.x, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

I have 3rd party code that I connect to via DataInputStream. The 3rd party code continually spits out information as it generates it. When something of interest comes across I want to pass it along to GraphQL Subscription(s)

I'm not sure how to wire the 3rd party code to the server-side GraphQL subscription code given this scenario. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Some conceptual code is below:

```
public void liveStream(DataInputStream in) {
  // Sit and constantly watch input stream and report when messages come in
  while(true) {
    SomeMessage message = readFromInputStream(in);
    System.out.println("Received Message Type:" + message.getType());

    // Convert SomeMessage into the appropriate class based on its type
    if (message.getType() == "foo") {
      Foo foo = convertMessageToFoo(message);
    } else if (message.getType() == "bar") {
      Bar bar = convertMessageToBar(message);
    } else if (howeverManyMoreOfThese) {
      // Keep converting to different objects
    }
  }       
}

// The client code will eventually trigger this method when 
// the GraphQL Subscription query is sent over
VertxDataFetcher<Publisher<SomeClassTBD>> myTestDataFetcher() {
  return new VertxDataFetcher<> (env, future) -> {
    try {
      future.complete(myTest());
    } catch(Exception e) {
      future.fail(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Here is an example of Vert.x GraphQL server with subscription https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/web-graphql-examples#apollo-subscriptions-server-and-client HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I wrapped my liveStream code in an ObservableOnSubscribe using an executorService and I'm getting back all the data. I guess I can now either pass it straight through to the front end or create separate publishers to deal with specific object types and have graphql subscriptions point to their respective publishers.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor;

ObservableOnSubscribe<SomeClassTBD> handler = emitter ->
  executor.submit(() -> {
    try {
      //liveStream code here
      emitter.onComplete();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      emitter.onError(e);
    }
    finally {
      // Cleanup here
    }
  });
  Observable<SomeClassTBD> = Observable.create(handler);
```